# java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError while reading xlsx file in Java/liferay

Tags: java, excel, exception, liferay, apache-poi

Hi I am trying to read excel (.xlsx) file in Liferay's web service call.

Here is my code

```
public JSONArray getProductListing() throws IOException,
        FileNotFoundException {
    try {

        JSONArray jArray = com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil
                .createJSONArray();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                new File(
                        "/home/onrule/GITLAB/OnRule-3.0-Core/XLS2SQL_Folder/XLS/product-portlet/PRODUCTS_DATA.xlsx"));

        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            // Create JSONArray for each row.
            JSONArray lineArray = com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil
                    .createJSONArray();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                lineArray.put(cell.getStringCellValue());

            }
            jArray.put(lineArray);
        }

        System.out.println("bye");
        return jArray;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:49)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:73)
at com.onrule.core.standard.service.impl.GrpServiceImpl.getProductListing(GrpServiceImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.<clinit>(AbstractNode.java:39)
... 107 more
```

for the first time when I try to invoke the web services.
but after this first time error changes to
Could not initialize class

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller

I have openxml4j jar in java build path already. Which contains **org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller** class as well.

I debugged my code and it works fine till `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);` line.

Does anybody has any solution?

Comment: Show us the (first) stacktrace.

Comment: @StephenC


`23:06:20,688 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-43][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:87] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

`23:06:23,045 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-36][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:87] Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller`

`23:07:04,647 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-50][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:87] Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller`

Comment: That isn't the complete stacktrace.  You have left out the nested exception where is says *what* the exception in the initializer actually was.

Comment: @StephenC , actually that is the only error I see on my console.

Comment: Well you need to adjust the logging levels to get it to print out full stacktraces.  Without a full stacktrace, you / we can only >guess< what the problem is.

Comment: Without the full stacktrace we can't tell what's going wrong, but my bet is on [you missing one of the POI dependencies - are you *sure* you've got all of them](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on your *runtime* classpath?

Comment: @StephenC , I have changed the stacktrace in the question itself. please take a look, Thanks

Comment: @Gagravarr please take a look at question, I have made changes in stacktrace there, thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using dom4j at all - do you perhaps have an ancient version of Apache POI on your classpath? Remove all old ones, and go with only 3.14 or better yet 3.15 beta 1

Comment: @Gagravarr , so just Apache POI » 3.15-beta1 ?
No other jars ?

Comment: You need to [follow the instructions on the Apache POI components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to see what POI jars you need and what their dependencies are. Or, let something like Maven or Gradle take care of it for you

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, I changed from XSSF to HSSF and it worked. with poi 3.15